# Getting a symmetrical Pie for Profit by Product Category Tableau

Tags: pie-chart

I am trying to get a simple visualization for Profit by Category.

I have a sales table for which i have calculated Total profit as Sales Amount - Return Amount- Total Costs

I have a table with the product Category name (around 7-8) categories.

1. Each Pie has to be the Product category
2. The size of the Pie has to be the profit

As per what I have done so far, we are applying the same logic -> Color coding the Product category and making the Sum(Total profits) which is a calculated field as the Size. We even tried making the angle as Sum(Total Profits). we are getting a pie that is symmetrical. Every pie has the same size.

Thank you in advance for your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you calculate the Profit ratio  SUM([Profit])/SUM([Sales]) ? Set it on label and see the numbers. If your Profit ratio doesn't have much difference you will see the bubbles to be identical in size. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZWTD.jpg)